# Where to create data controllers in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm really new to CI and trying to keep the best layout I can, as true to CI that I can, and I'm having difficulty figuring out where I should put a class to control data.

Lets say I need to keep track of a lot of movies, so I'll need a class defining what variables a movie has. Currently, I have a model that loads a library when it needs to access/modify a movie. The model has a public variable to store the array of movies and some functions for modifying that and then working with the database. The library is used for initializing a single movie and gathering whatever data is needed from whatever sources needed.

So, should I make a helper that has a class with all the variables a movie needs? I'm just trying to get the best organization I can and this can obviously be rather subjective so I'm hoping someone has an answer that's closer to my style. Thanks for reading and for any help provided.

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer to use a top level MY_Controller which extends CI_Controller in the core folder and then have all controllers extend MY_Controller. That way you can create objects in MY_Controller that are accessible throughout the application.

Comment: That doesn't sound like it would scale very well (read: I don't want to clutter up my primary Controller with hundreds of lines of class code). What I currently have is a Model for each data object with a private variable to store an array of whatever class it uses, and the classes are Helpers. May not be the best way to go about it, but it works and keeps my files pretty clean.